# Adding Shadows to UIViews

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, offset, shadow

I have been scouring on and off for a few days now how to properly add a drop shadow to a UIView. There are many resources on the topic, but none so far have worked for me. The shadow does not appear.

```
 cell.buttonView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
 cell.buttonView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(4, 4)
 cell.buttonView.layer.shadowRadius = 5
 cell.buttonView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
 cell.buttonView.layer.masksToBounds = false
```

Altering masksToBounds was because the absence of that step in another person's code seemed to be the reason as to why they could not get their shadow to appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is good (and works, just tried it). The problem must be somewhere else.

Note that the shadow will only apply if your view has content. So if your view's `backgroundColor` is `clearColor` it won't display the shadow.

Also check your code is running and not runned only in some cases ;)

Comment: Well it had a background color and that is it. Does that suffice as content?

Comment: @dyllandry Yes it should. From my tests. Could you give us more infos about buttonView ? Is it a simple UIView ? Do you have code altering it ? Do you custom draw ?

Comment: It is within a tableViewController as a component of a prototype cell. I linked it up to my tableViewCell class as an IBOutlet. I have a tableViewController that makes a bunch of them in a series. The only code that alters the buttonView is a single if statement before that will change it's background to color to either red or green before I add shadows.

Comment: Strange, don't really see what could play a role… Could you make a screenshot ?

Comment: Here is an imgur album to everything regarding this buttonView. Keep in mind, the buttonView is just the green colored portion at the button. The text you see is part of an actual UIButton that spans on top of the entire picture and buttonView.

http://imgur.com/a/qS2YO

Comment: Hum I really don't see what could be wrong… Everything looks fine to me =/

Comment: Are you sure you are going through this code ? Breakpoint to verify.

Comment: 100% sure- nevermind... It was in a portion of code that is only ever run in very unique situations. Moving it out of their works. Thanks a lot Fant aha..

Comment: Glad I could help ;) Updated my answer so you can mark it as the right answer.